# Multiple Active Record Query vs. One Query & Parsing in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

What would be the best practice when returning multiple, simple active record queries vs. one query and then performing calculations on the subqueries.

For example, a Lectures model has a teacher_id column and a state column. Which would be better for performance:

1. Running three active record queries to return three hashes for lectures with a teacher id and a certain state.
2. Running one active record query to return all lectures with a teacher_id, and then parsing this hash and returning three separate hashes based on the states within the original hash?

Comment: Do you query each teacher ID with a different state, or same state for all ID's?

Comment: No I'm querying one teacher id with three different states. Think separating a teachers lectures into active or inactive

Comment: So why not query `Lectures.where(teacher_id: 123, state: ["State1", "State2", "State3"])`? That's one AR query which will fetch all 3 matching records.

Comment: I wanted to return three different hashes, not just one with all the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two options you've provided is so trivial that you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks, was just curious. I figured the first was a Rails method vs the second lower level ruby manipulation so there would be a difference. Maybe I don't understand it as well but appreciate the advice to focus on other issues

Comment: In actuality, it would depend so much on things you haven't mentioned like how many rows you have, what the spread of rows is across the three different states, etc. This is not a question that has a definitive answer in all situations.

Comment: Oh wow that is interesting. Not sure what spread means, but I'm assuming there would be a lot of rows, and the states would just be different string literals "ACTIVE", "INACTIVE", and maybe a few other states. This was just more out of curiosity

Comment: Spread is just how many are in each category, like if there were a lot in a single category and very few in the others, then that'll affect the performance of each different option.